# Load testing for java client/server application

Tags: java, load-testing

I have written a java client server application (not http), which i need to load test. However, most tools out there such as jmeter and grinder seem to be targeted to http requests. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since we have no idea what protocol you're using, write your own client in a way easily extendable for load testing.

Answer (score 1):

JMeter allows writing pluginns. If your application uses protocol other than HTTP it seems that the protocol is proprietary,  so writing tests requires some custom implementation anyway. JMeter allows this and it is highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at [Soatest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soatest) which claims to be socket based and should be able to use whichever web protocol you are using (hopefully TCP/UDP).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `JUnit4` or `JUnit5` based load runners below which can simply accept your Unit tests and generate load on the target server. These need not be HTTP tests, these could be any tests annotated with `@Test`

- [JUnit4 based load runner](https://github.com/authorjapps/zerocode/wiki/Load-or-Performance-Testing-(IDE-based)#flexibility)
- [JUnit5 based load runner](https://github.com/authorjapps/zerocode/wiki/JUnit5-Jupiter-Parallel-Load-Extension)

The load configs look like below to ramp up or ramp down your load:

```
number.of.threads=2
ramp.up.period.in.seconds=10
loop.count=1
```

Your load test will look like below:

```java
@LoadWith("our_load_config.properties")
@TestMapping(testClass = AnyTestEndPoint.class, testMethod = "anyTestMethod")
@RunWith(ZeroCodeLoadRunner.class)
public class LoadTest {

}
```

Your JUnit test which is fed to the load generator,
The test class looks like below:

```java
import org.junit.Test;

public class AnyTestEndPoint {

    @Test
    public void anyTestMethod() throws Exception {
       ...
       // You can have your client code invoking the target server
       ...
    }
}
```

Note:
You can feed multiple `Junit` tests too to the load reactor, to generate load on different part of the server logic/apis/processes.

Visit the [HelloWorld Examples](https://github.com/authorjapps/performance-tests#multi-scenario-parallel-load) for more details.